# PHP & JSON Parsing

Tags: php, json

I have read a few Q&As on here and additional articles, but cannot get this script to display the relevant values from the JSON return (which are long and lat from this Google Maps call).

```
<?php

// Address for Google to search
$address = 'London,UK';

// Get the map json data from Google Maps using the $address variable
$googleCall = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . $address .'&sensor=false';

$json = file_get_contents($googleCall);
//header("Content-type: application/json");
//echo $json;

echo $json->results->geometry->location->lat;
echo $json->results->geometry->location->lng;
?>
```

I am sure I am 99% there, just cannot see where the error is.

Comment: `json_decode` is missing in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decode your `json` as an associative array and the access to all data with scopes

```
$address = 'London,UK';
$googleCall = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . $address .'&sensor=false';

$json = file_get_contents($googleCall);
$array = json_decode($json, true); //note second parameter on true as we need associative array

echo $array['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'] . '<br>';
echo $array['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
```

This will output

```
51.5112139
-0.1198244
```

Comment: You can access all data without making it an associative array.

Comment: Out of interest, most articles didnt wrap the values in ''. Should it be either way or is this the 'right' way.

Comment: @PHP-L-Driver without quotes php will throw notice about using undefined constants

Comment: @PHP-L-Driver you are welcome dude. If you feel answer was correct and it helped you out please consider to accept it, so you will also help people in the future with similar problems. To accept you just need to click on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.

Comment: Just curious though, why the `,true`? I know it makes it an associative array, but why?

Comment: @Dave I've written a comment on code: `//note second parameter on true as we need associative array`

Comment: @Dave so I would be able to access as associative array using keys in scopes

Comment: It looks nice don't get me wrong, but what's wrong with the OO approach?

Comment: I just like more associative array though

Answer (score 0):

use `json_decode` here documentation
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
<?php

// Address for Google to search
$address = 'London,UK';

// Get the map json data from Google Maps using the $address variable
$googleCall = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . $address .'&sensor=false';

$json = file_get_contents($googleCall);

$json = json_decode($json);


echo $json->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
echo $json->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had similar code in before, but it didn't display a result. The same is with your code above.

Am I reading the JSON data incorrectly?

Comment: @PHP-L-Driver i update my answer , i found http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=London,UK&sensor=false‌​ return data in result[0]

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
<?php

// Address for Google to search
$address = 'London,UK';

// Get the map json data from Google Maps using the $address variable
$googleCall = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . $address .'&sensor=false';

$json = file_get_contents($googleCall);

$json = json_decode($json);
//header("Content-type: application/json");
//echo $json;

echo $json->results->geometry->location->lat;
echo $json->results->geometry->location->lng;
?>
```